# Convertir archivos en nodejs a .PDF

Tags: nodejs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buen día, estoy usando la libreria libre-convert para convertir archivos a .pdf, todo me va bien si mando solo un archivo y espero un tiempo para enviar el siguiente, pero si los mando seguidos tengo un error, pareciera que la Liberia sigue trabajando con al anterior y entonces truena cuando llega el siguiente, que me recomiendan hacer? les pego la función que lo hace, es la que mando llamar cada que se sube un archivo, soy novato en node asi que agradeceré cualquier sugerencia:

```
async function convert(name=''){
  try {
    let arr = name.split('.')
    const enterPath = path.join(__dirname, '../uploads/pdfs/', '', name);    
    const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, `../uploads/${arr[0]}.pdf`);
    // Read file
    let data = await fs.readFile(enterPath)
    let done = await lib_convert(data, '.pdf', undefined)
    await fs.writeFile(outputPath, done)
    return { success: true, fileName: arr[0] };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return { success: false }[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error?

Comment: Hola Robinson, agregue la imagen del error, creo que el problema es que solo se puede ejecutar una instancia a la vez de libre-convert y si esta en proceso y le llega otro falla, veo que en node se pueden ejecutar procesos "child" pero no entiendo como hacerlo :( ¿alguna idea de como ejecutar cada vez que se llame en un proceso child distinto? :(

Comment: Claro, si quieres leer sobre los procesos child, puedes leer un poco acá: https://solidgeargroup.com/invocacion-de-procesos-en-segundo-plano-desde-nodejs/